# allocating size using new operator

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

I HAVE TWO DOUBTS REGARDING NEW OPERATOR

1.)

```
int a[20];
```

the above statement allocates memory of size 20 in the  array a

```
int a=new int[20];
```

this statement also does the same thing then why should i go with the new operator
when it is so easy to allocate size by array

2.)
why is it that new operator is always used to allocate size to only pointer variables
like

```
   int *p;
    p=new int[100];
```

it is not used to allocate size to the ordinary variables

Comment: What if you don't know the size you want to allocate in advance? Also, stack overflow problem when the size is big.

Comment: First of all the code is not correct: int[] a = new int[20]. Then you have to study a lot before to ask such a bad question...

Comment: @LPs: `int[] a` is wrong, it needs to be `int* a` instead.

Comment: @LPs: You're talking Java I believe.

Comment: you can't do like this `int a=new int[20];`

Answer (score 1):

> int a[20];

Allocates on the stack, size must be known at compile time.

> int *a=new int[20];

Allocates on the heap, size does not need to be known at compile time, can be specified at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a[20];
```

allocates memory on stack.

```
int *a=new int[20];
```

allocates memory on heap.

*Advantage of heap over stack:-*

You get control over that memory i.e it's you who would choose when you don't need that memory and hence delete it in contrast to stack memory.

*Disadvantage of heap over stack:-*

Accessing heap memory is bit slower than accessing stack memory and if you miss delete on that memory than it would result in memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

new[20] creates "dynamic" memory (on the heap). [20] creates memory on the stack.

with new you can do stuff like this:

```
std::vector<int*> my_std_vector;

for(int i=0; i < atoi(argv[1]); ++i) {
  int *my_int = new int[20];
  my_std_vector.push_back(my_int);
}
```

some examples: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new%5B%5D/

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with using definitions of arrays like this.

```
int a[20];
```

This statement allocates the array either in the static memory or on the stack depending on the context where the statement is used. Usually the stack has a limited size. So for large arrays defined on the stack a program can crash.

The other problem is that ths size of an array in C++ shall be a compile time constant expression. If the size of an array should be determined at run time then you have to use the new operator as in your example if it is written correctly:

```
size_t n = 20;

int *a = new int[n];
```

There is also another problem. For example you may not return arrays from functions and you may not return a pointer to first element of a local array. So the only way either to return a pointer to a dynamically allocated array or to wrap an array in a structure. But the last way is inefficient for large arrays.

Operator new may be used for allocating a single object. For example

```
int *p = int( 10 );
```

The most often the new operator for single objects is used when you need to allocate a class object.